# VueJS replace data of component // same route problem

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have a '/posts' route. This 'posts' route has a created() function which fetches data from an API via GET and outputs the data to the page.

Now I have a navbar which is included on every page. This navbar now has an input field where I can search certain posts by tags. This tag based search function is already working and runs via POST to an api.

Now the problem:

I write some tags into input field in the navigation and search for them. If I'm currently not  at the posts route, the search works fine and I get directed to the posts route and see the tag related posts.

If I write some tags in the navbar input field and press the search button, WHILE i'm already on the posts route, nothing happens.

So if I'm in any other route then '/posts', the tag based search works great.

Thats why I think, the problem is, that I'm already on the '/posts' route. But it should also work this way! So I need something like a route link that replaces/refresh the route content?

Here is my code:

Relevant part of my navbar component:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/posts" class="nav-link">Posts</router-link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <div v-for="(tag, index) in tags" class="ml-sm-2">
                    <h6><span class="badge badge-light" @click="removeSearchTags(index)">{{ tag }}</span></h6>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control ml-1 mr-sm-2" type="text" v-model="tag" v-on:keyup.enter="pushToTags"
                       placeholder="Search Gaming, Youtube, DrunkSlut" aria-label="Search">
                <router-link :to="{name: 'posts', params: { searchTags: tags }}" reload>
                        <button type="button" v-if="this.tags.length > 0"
                                class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0">Search
                        </button>
                </router-link>
            </form>
```

Whole posts component logic:

```
    <script>
    export default {
        name: "posts",
        data: function () {
            return {
                apiUrl: '/getPosts',

                posts: '',
                submitted: false,

                first_page_url: '',
                last_page_url: '',
                current_page_url: '',

                next_page_url: '',
                prev_page_url: '',

                lastPage: '',
                current_page: '',

                tags: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getPosts: function (url) {
                this.$http.get(url).then(function (data) {
                    this.posts = data.body.data;
                    this.first_page_url = data.body.first_page_url;
                    this.last_page_url = data.body.last_page_url;
                    this.next_page_url = data.body.next_page_url;
                    this.current_page = data.body.current_page;
                    this.prev_page_url = data.body.prev_page_url;
                    this.lastPage = data.body.last_page;
                    this.current_page_url = '/getPosts?page=' + this.current_page;
                });
            },
            getPostByTags: function (url, tags) {
                this.$http.post(url, {
                    tags: tags
                }).then(function (data) {
                    this.posts = data.body.data;
                    this.first_page_url = data.body.first_page_url;
                    this.last_page_url = data.body.last_page_url;
                    this.next_page_url = data.body.next_page_url;
                    this.current_page = data.body.current_page;
                    this.prev_page_url = data.body.prev_page_url;
                    this.lastPage = data.body.last_page;
                    this.current_page_url = '/getPostByTags?page=' + this.current_page;
                });
            },
        },
        computed: {},
        created() {
            if (!this.$route.params.searchTags) {
                this.getPosts(this.apiUrl);
            } else {
                this.getPostByTags('/getPostByTags', this.$route.params.searchTags);
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

The Main html file, where vueJS starts. There is only the navbar component, thats how it's included on any other route.

```
<div id="app">
    <navbar></navbar>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: I've found this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1490 -- and the hook: beforeRouteEnter. Still doesn't really understand how I can use this

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your `created` as a `watch`

Something like:

```
watch: {
    '$route.params.searchTags': {
        deep: true,
        immediate: true, // this triggers the watch on component creation, so you can remove the created hook content
        handler() {
            if (!this.$route.params.searchTags) {
                this.getPosts(this.apiUrl);
            } else {
                this.getPostByTags('/getPostByTags', this.$route.params.searchTags);
            }
        }
    }
}
```